# Can one obtain the alias name used to call a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Given the Bash script below (let's call it `foo.sh`):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat <<EOF
\$0: $0
\$BASH_SOURCE: ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
EOF
```

And then creating an alias to it

```bsh
$ alias bar='./foo.sh'
```

When executing `bar`, the output is below:

```bsh
$ bar
$0: ./foo.sh
$BASH_SOURCE: ./foo.sh
```

I would like to know if there is a variable or any other method to obtain (from within the script itself) the **command/alias name** that was used to call the script—in this case `bar`. The desired output would be e.g.

```bsh
$ bar
$0: ./foo.sh
$BASH_SOURCE: ./foo.sh
$SOME_MAGIC_VARIABLE: bar
```

My reason for wanting this is to be able to share code/functions in the same script file but execute differently depending on *how* the command was called. Sort of like the way `uptime` and `w` are identical binaries, but perform different functions based on their invocation.

Comment: There's no way to do this just with an alias: it's rewritten by the shell and is never seen by the command. Some possible solutions would be to change your alias to explicitly set a variable, or to use a symlink instead of an alias, both of which are traceable (the latter with `$0`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271224/how-to-get-name-of-alias-that-invoked-bash-script

Comment: @ChrisDown Thank you for the advice. I ended up using the symlink method you suggested, along with `$0`. It works well. If you want to post that as an answer I can mark it as such.